# Handling particular constraint errors in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a changeset with a unique constraint on one of the fields:

```
defmodule Oauth.Shop do
  use Ecto.Model
  import Ecto.Changeset
  alias Ecto.Changeset

  schema "shops" do
    field :shop, :string
    field :access_token, :string
    field :scope, :string
    field :active, :boolean
    timestamps
  end

  def changeset(shop, params \\ %{}) do
    shop
    |> cast(params, [:shop, :access_token, :scope, :active])
    |> Changeset.validate_required([:shop, :access_token, :scope, :active])
    |> unique_constraint(:shop)
  end
end
```

In one of the controllers, I insert a new shop. However, if a duplicate shop is being created, an exception is raised:

```
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (Ecto.ConstraintError) constraint error when attempting to insert model:

    * unique: shops_shop_index
```

Here is the code where I save the record:

```
  def save_shop({:ok, access_params}, shop) do
    Repo.insert(%Shop{shop: shop, access_token: access_params.access_token, scope: access_params.scope})
    hook_uninstall(shop, access_params.access_token)
    {:ok}
  end
```

Note that %Shop is a struct, while the variable shop is just a value from a query string parameter.

Although I could create a plug for Ecto.ConstraintError, I feel this won't give the the granular control I need for detailed user feedback.

What is a good way to catch the exception and notify the user that the shop has already been registered?

Comment: how are you inserting into the db? are you using `Repo.insert!` or `Repo.insert`? Because according to the [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#unique_constraint/3), the latter should return a two tuple `{:error, changeset}` which you can easily pattern match on

Comment: Are you sure you're passing a `Changeset` to `Repo.insert` and not the struct directly?

Comment: @Dogbert et al . . . Updated question to include the Repo.insert().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the `Ecto.Changeset` returned by `Shop.changeset/2` to `Repo.insert` and not a `Shop` struct directly if you want the validations and unique_constraint defined in that function to have any effect. You'll also have to use pattern matching to handle the error case.

```
def save_shop({:ok, access_params}, shop) do
  case Repo.insert(Shop.changeset(%Shop{}, %{shop: shop, access_token: access_params.access_token, scope: access_params.scope})) do
    {:ok, _} ->
      hook_uninstall(shop, access_params.access_token)
      {:ok}
    {:error, changeset} ->
      # Put whatever value you want to return in case of an error here.
      # You can get more details about the error using `changeset.errors`.
      {:error}
  end
end
```

(I've assumed you only want to run `hook_uninstall` if the insert is successful. If that's not the case you can copy that line to the other branch or move it outside the `case`.)

It's also considered more idiomatic to use pattern matching when possible instead of accessing a Map's field using `.field`:

```
def save_shop({:ok, %{access_token: access_token, scope: scope}}, shop) do
  case Repo.insert(Shop.changeset(%Shop{}, %{shop: shop, access_token: access_token, scope: scope})) do
    {:ok, _} ->
      hook_uninstall(shop, access_token)
      {:ok}
    {:error, changeset} ->
      # Put whatever value you want to return in case of an error here.
      # You can get more details about the error using `changeset.errors`.
      {:error}
  end
end
```

Comment: I see how this works, thanks. Typo in the second example, second line: missing closing parenthesis. Thanks for helping me see a solution and the idiomatic implementation. I am still breaking some old habits and need to be reminded about pattern matching.

Comment: Fixed the typo, thanks. Glad that helped! Pattern matching can take some time to get used to, but once you understand it well, you'll miss it every time you have to use a language without pattern matching.